# How to convert MacCyrillic (x-mac-cyrillic, CP10007) to UTF-8 in PHP?

Tags: php, utf-8, cyrillic

I have MacCyrillic-encoded text, for example:

```
<f>–¢–µ–Ї—Г—Й–Є–є —Б—З–µ—В</f>
```

How can I convert it to UTF-8 in PHP?

I'm getting these errors:

> ```
> iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from x-mac-cyrillic to UTF-8 is not allowed.
> iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from CP10007 to `UTF-8' is not allowed
> iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from CP-10007 to UTF-8 is not allowed
> ```

I've also tried this:

```
<?php
$text = '<f>–¢–µ–Ї—Г—Й–Є–є —Б—З–µ—В</f>';
echo iconv('macintosh', 'UTF-8', $text) . PHP_EOL;
echo iconv('windows-1251', 'UTF-8', convert_cyr_string($text, 'm', 'w'));
```

But it doesn't work either. Please, help me. Thank you.

Comment: You say your data is `x-mac-cyrillic` and/or `CP10007` but don't even attempt to feed `iconv()` with that :-?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario I tried, but it not valid encoding names. 
iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from x-mac-cyrillic to UTF-8 is not allowed. | iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from CP10007 to `UTF-8' is not allowed | iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from CP-10007 to UTF-8 is not allowed

Comment: I've moved the information into the question, where it belongs to. Please have a look at my answer and test whether it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list of supported encodings can be found in the [libiconv library website](http://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) (that's the underlying library that gets the job done). Apparently, you need to do something like this:

```
echo iconv('MacCyrillic', 'UTF-8', $text) . PHP_EOL;
```